# Convert ArrayRealVector to Double[] in java

Tags: java

Convert ArrayRealVector to Double[]

```
ArrayRealVector pvData = new ArrayRealVector(pvSignal.getScaledY());
```

Comment: what is the problem you encounter? what is the error

Comment: i want to convert ArrayRealVector to Double[]

Comment: What have you tried so far and what results are you getting?

Comment: @sam - welcome to SO ! if you want to get real help please specify what have you tried and what was the problem with all the relevant data (exception and which example you used)

Comment: ` double c = Double.parseDouble(DataPreProcessor.preprocess(preScaledYSignal).toArray().toString());`  I tried to convert the ArrayRealVector to Double[] but is only pasilble to double

Comment: You should write some english sentences to explain your problem in more detail. And what is `ArrayRealVector`? When you use third-party library classes you should mention the library name.

Comment: It is also recommended for new users to read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) especially [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :
`ArrayRealVector pvData = new ArrayRealVector(pvSignal.getScaledY());
double[] a = pvData.toarray();
Double [] b = ArrayUtils.toObject(a);`